# python script, recursive directory

Tags: python, recursion, directory

I have the following code and I need to make it recursive (that it not only renames files in that one folder, but also in the folders in that folder etc...)

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez/untitled.*"):
    print(file)

import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for source_name in glob.glob("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez/untitled.*"):
    path, fullname = os.path.split(source_name)
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fullname)
    target_name = os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(current_day, ext))
    os.rename(source_name, target_name)
```

Comment: I bet `os.walk` would be useful. It recurses by default.

Comment: how do i need to implement that in my code?

Answer (score 0):

> how do i need to implement that in my code?

Something like that:

```
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez"):
    for f in files:
        if not f.startswith("untitled."):
            continue
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fullname)
        source_name = os.path.join(root, f)
        target_name = os.path.join(root, '{}{}'.format(current_day, ext))
        os.rename(source_name, target_name)
```

Comment: Its not working yet, it only renames the files in "Artez"

Comment: @malina It should work in all subdirectories of "Artez". Or do you want to work on all subdirectories of your Desktop?

Comment: @malina This won't recurse, since it is required to call a function in itself to recurse and this doesn't do that. It only deals with files, so it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def walk_dir(path):
    current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):    
        for filename in files:
            current = root + "/" + filename
            if os.path.isfile(current):
                print "ORIGINAL NAME: " + current
                ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
                target_name = os.path.join(root, '{}{}'.format(current_day, ext))
                print "NEW NAME: " + target_name
                os.rename(current, target_name)

walk_dir("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez")
```

I ran `walk_dir()` on a directory containing subdirectories and files. Only files are renamed. Output:

```
>>> walk_dir("dir1")
ORIGINAL NAME: dir1/i_am_a_file_in_dir1.doc
NEW NAME: dir1/2016-03-07.doc
ORIGINAL NAME: dir1/dir2/file_in_dir2_saying_hi
NEW NAME: dir1/dir2/2016-03-07
ORIGINAL NAME: dir1/dir2/dir3/file_nested
NEW NAME: dir1/dir2/dir3/2016-03-07
ORIGINAL NAME: dir1/dir2/dir3/dir3file
NEW NAME: dir1/dir2/dir3/2016-03-07
ORIGINAL NAME: dir1/dir2/another_dir_at_level2/level2_dir2_file.extension
NEW NAME: dir1/dir2/another_dir_at_level2/2016-03-07.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call a function inside itself in order to recurse.
A way to do it:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

def rename_files(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for source_name in next(os.walk('.'))[2]:
        path, fullname = os.path.split(source_name)
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(fullname)
        target_name = os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(current_day, ext))
        os.rename(source_name, target_name)
    for dir_name in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
        rename_files(dir_name)
    os.chdir('..')


rename_files("/Users/shirin/Desktop/Artez")
```